# How do I exit out of this while loop?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, exit

Here is my code. My programs does everything I need it too but how would I exit out of the while loop?? Tried different options but nothings worked yet. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated. Much thanks for your time.

P.S. (I'm wanting to exit out of the loop by user input) so when they type 999 its prints out thank you and ends.

```
package project02;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project02 
{



public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Declaring variables for a,b,and c
        double a = 1;
        double b = 8;
        double c = 16;

        //Declaring variables for roots
        double x1 = 0;
        double x2 = 0;

        //Discremenent
        double d = (Math.pow(b, 2) - 4*a*c);

        //Inputs
        System.out.println("Input the values a, b, and c for ax^2+bx+c = 0");
        System.out.println("Input a: ");
        a = scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Input b: ");
        b = scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Input c: ");
        c = scan.nextDouble();

        while (d != 999)
    {   
        if (d > 0)
        {
            x1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c))/2*a;
            x2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c))/2*a;

            System.out.println("Root 1 is: " + x1);
            System.out.println("Root 2 is: " + x2);
        }
        else if (d == 0)
        {
            x1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c))/2*a;

            System.out.println("There is only one real root at x = " + x1);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("There are no real roots");
        }
        System.out.println("\n" + "Input the values a, b, and c for ax^2+bx+c = 0 or enter 999 to      stop.");

        System.out.println("Input a: ");
        a = scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Input b: ");
        b = scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Input c: ");
        c = scan.nextDouble();

    }   
        System.out.println("Thank you!!!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set d to 999 in order for the while loop to exit. I don't see that in your code. The other option would be to use 'break'. For example:

```
System.out.println("Input a: "); 
a = scan.nextDouble();
if(a == 999) {
    break;
}
```

Or

```
System.out.println("Input a: "); 
a = scan.nextDouble();
if(a == 999) {
    d = 999;
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are never setting the "d" variable, so that means its never 999. 
you need to read the input from the user and set the d variable inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you need to `break` out of the while loop when a = 999.

Like so:

```
System.out.println("Input a: ");
a = scan.nextDouble();

if(a == 999) break;
```

As for the entire program, I would have used a `do while` loop instead.

Like this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

//Variable for continue.
String response = "n";

//Declaring variables for a,b,and c
double a = 1;
double b = 8;
double c = 16;

//Declaring variables for roots
double x1 = 0;
double x2 = 0;

//Discremenent
double d = (Math.pow(b, 2) - 4*a*c);



do
{   
    //Inputs
    System.out.println("Input the values a, b, and c for ax^2+bx+c = 0");
    System.out.println("Input a: ");
    a = scan.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Input b: ");
    b = scan.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Input c: ");
    c = scan.nextDouble();

    if (d > 0)
    {
        x1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c))/2*a;
        x2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c))/2*a;

        System.out.println("Root 1 is: " + x1);
        System.out.println("Root 2 is: " + x2);
    }
    else if (d == 0)
    {
        x1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c))/2*a;

        System.out.println("There is only one real root at x = " + x1);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("There are no real roots");
    }
    System.out.println("Continue?(y/n)");
    response = scan.next();

} while(response.equalsIgnoreCase("y");

System.out.println("Thank you!!!");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I went back and tried it your way but for this part of the code:     System.out.println("Continue?(y/n)");
    response = scan.nextChar();                                                                                                                          I get an error for scan.nextChar();for some reason...

Comment: I've edited the code. I confused Java with another language. .nextChar() doesn't exist. Instead use a String for your variable. I also changed the comparison in the while() to something cleaner.

Comment: Finally got it working. Appreciate all the help my man. And no worries lol many Thanks!